# Nginx - what is the utility of the fastcgi_index directive?

Tags: nginx

I'm working with the book *Nginx From Beginner to Pro* and I'm wondering what is the utility of the fastcgi_index directive in the FastCGI optional module ?

In the book is noted that:

> This option sets a file name that will be appended after a URI.
>   Example: fastcgi_index index.php;

But I can't figure out the concrete utility of this configuration.

I have made some research on the web but I have found nothing very relevant to explain the utility of this directive.

Someone would please explain us the concept behind the scene ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think it set a default file's name for FastCGI server if the URI end with a slash. [You can read the doc here.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_index)